# Saving multiple data as foreign key using select2 on laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, jquery-select2

I have a form where a subject can be assigned to multiple programs. The programs are already saved on DB in another table and I am calling them to the form and selecting programs using select2 multiple selections.

```
            <form action="{{ route('general_subject_store') }}" method="post">
                @csrf
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Subject Name <sup>*</sup></label>
                    <input placeholder="Subject Name" type="text" name="subjectName" id="subjectName" class="form-control" />
                </div>       
                <div class="form-group" style="padding:0px;">
                    <label>Programs(Class) <sup>*</sup></label>
                    <select data-placeholder="Select Classes" name="general_program_level_id[]" class="js-example-basic-multiple js-states form-control" multiple="multiple" style="width: 100%; height:100%;" required>
                        @foreach($gpls as $pl)
                            <option value="{{ $pl->id }}">{{ $pl->program_name }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                </div>
                <br>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-md btn-info">
            </form>
```

GeneralProgramLevel:

```
public function generalSubjects()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(GeneralSubject::class);
    }
```

GeneralSubject:

```
public function generalProgramLevel(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\GeneralProgramLevel');
    }
```

The store function in the controller goes as:

```
public function generalSubjectStore(Request $request){
        $subjectName = $request->get('subjectName');
        $program = $request->get('general_program_level_id');

        $subject = new GeneralSubject;
        $subject->subjectName = $subjectName;
        
        $subject->general_program_level_id = $program;
        
        dd($subject);
        $subject->save();

        Session::flash('success', 'Subject Added!');
        return redirect(route('general_subject'));
    }
```

The Migration is like:

```
Schema::create('general_subjects', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('subjectName');
            
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('general_program_level_id');
            $table->foreign('general_program_level_id')->references('id')->on('general_program_levels');

            $table->timestamps();

            $table->boolean('isDeleted')->default(false);
            $table->dateTime('deletedAt')->nullable();

        });
```

The dump attribute of $subject is:

```
#attributes: array:2 [▼
    "subjectName" => "Mathmatics"
    "general_program_level_id" => array:2 [▼
      0 => "1"
      1 => "2"
    ]
  ]
```

I want to save the data in the database and is not saving. Please help me

Comment: if are you using pivot table . there is method .. otherwise you need to use loop..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Insert multiple records from one form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62616115/laravel-insert-multiple-records-from-one-form)

Comment: did you find solution ?

Comment: @AbdullahAlNoor I tried but multiple data for multiple program selected.. Check it 
https://imgur.com/a/NNP39a5